# How do I handle the exception if one or two files don't exist?

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if one or two files exist like this:

```
def check_files_if_exist():
    try:
        f1 = open(file1)
        f1.close()
        f2 = open(file2)
        f2.close()
    except:
        #how to pass exception if one or two files does not exist?
```

My question is how do I pass an exception if of one or both files does not exist?

Comment: Why not just use `os.path.exists()`? (from the built-in `os.path` module)

Comment: What do you mean "pass an exception"? Do you want to raise an error?

Comment: Also, won't you need to pass `file1` and `file2` as arguments to `check_files_if_exist`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `os.path.exists()` or `os.path.isfile()` from the built-in `os.path` module, you'll have to use two try-except blocks:

```
def check_files_if_exists(...):
    try:
        f1 = open(...)
        f1.close()
    except:
        return False # Return False because the path doesn't exist
    try:
        f2 = open(...)
        f2.close()
    except:
        return False # Return False because the path doesn't exist
    return True # This only occurs when both files exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly check if a file exist by using the [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module. It comes with python.

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('/path/to/file.txt')
if p.exists():
    # open file...
    with p.open('r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            # Do something here...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `os.path.isfile(path)` to check whether file exists, without any exception.

```
import os

def check_files_if_exist(path1, path2):
  return os.path.isfile(path1) and os.path.isfile(path2)
```

or

```
import os

def check_files_if_exist(*paths):
  return all(os.path.isfile(path) for path in paths)
```

Comment: If the function is just to check whether the files exist, there's no need to open and close them. Just `return True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_files_if_exist():
    try:
        f1 = open(file1)
        f1.close()
        f2 = open(file2)
        f2.close()
    except:
        pass  # if you want to stop the whole function, you can use "return False" here.
```

I don't know the scenario of the author. If you want to just stop the function, you can use `return False`. But if you still want to execute some function even the `file1` and `file2` doesn't exists, you can use pass to ignore the exception.